# ODE water drop modeling question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

I have been working on a ODE homework which involves modeling the velocity of a drop of water falling from the sky. The ODE that models its velocity is given by:

$$
mv'=kv^2-mg, \qquad
k=\frac{1}{2}C_{d}\rho _{a},
$$
$C_{d}$: friction,
$\rho_{a}$: air density,
$A$: transversal section of the water drop.

I have had to find the theoretical velocity limit of the water drop as a function of $A$ by solving directly the ODE and compare these results with Euler and Runge-Kutta IV methods on MATLAB. **I have done all of that.**

The last question of my homework is an open question: It asks to modify the ODE presented by imagining now that the water drop losses a fraction of mass (by evaporation) while it is falling. I will have to apply Euler and Runge-Kutta IV on this new ODE. So I am looking for suggestions to improve the equation. Mass $m$ now is going to be a function of time, it has to decrease. I have been thinking to assume that the water drops are spheres and by using $density * volume=mass$.

Thank you very much in advanced!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should just be able to write that the mass $m$ is a function of time and perhaps assume a linear one, namely

$$ m(t)=m_0-st,$$ where $m_0$ is an initial mass and $s$ is the rate of loss (positive) in units of $\frac{mass}{time}$. Then your equation is no longer separable (but who cares if you're going to solve in numerically) and would look like

$$ v'=\frac{k}{m(t)} v^{2} -g,  $$ or

$$ v'=\frac{k}{m_0-st} v^{2} -g,  $$

Hope this helps some. Is this what you're looking for?

Cheers,

Paul Safier

Comment: The model for the change of mass is simple but looks OK for an easy calculation. I think a more sophisticated one could be $\frac{\partial \rho }{\partial t}=-\frac{1}{r^2 }\frac{\partial }{\partial r}\left\lbrack r^2 \rho \;v\right\rbrack$ (https://vrs.amsi.org.au/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2014/09/ALROE_Joel._Research_Paper_revised.pdf), but it would depend on your aim.